# How do I delete my scifi.SE profile only?

Tags: support, user-accounts

I want to delete my Scifi profile. I had a series of questions and answers bad received, flagged for wrong reasons etc (a question that should have been marked as "opinion based" was just marked as a duplicate and was not a duplicate, also for each up vote someone given someone else give a downvote). So I don't think this community is for me, however I don't want to delete the whole network profile, just the scifi section. Thanks.

This must be a bug. there is no delete button here:

[image]

Comment: [This way](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/deleting-account).

Comment: *"If you have voted or posted, please contact the Stack Exchange Team"*

Comment: FYI: I agree with you on the duplicate question, it's been queued for reopening, so perhaps you should give it a few more days before you make a decision?

Comment: I’m voting to reopen too. It’s primarily opinion-based, and by no means a duplicate.

Comment: If you want to delete your account, that’s fine. But maybe try taking a break instead (that way you get to keep your questions, privileges, and so forth if you ever want to come back). The fruitarian question was actually good, and probably attracted some downvotes from (a) people who dislike questions about the history of sci-fi/real life, and from people who thought that the question was too trivial to answer. The other *was* “primarily opinion-based”, but my first question got closed too. It’s not too bad, all told, for that to happen.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### **To answer your question...**

From the [help centre](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/deleting-account):

> If you have voted or posted, please contact the Stack Exchange Team:
>
> Visit the [**contact form**](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/contact) and select 'I need to delete my user profile.' After you contact us, the team will reach out with further instructions.

Since you have voted and posted on this site, you can't delete your profile with a single click; you need to contact SE and ask them to delete your profile for you.

### **To address your complaints about the community...**

> a question that should have been marked as "opinion based" was just marked as a duplicate and was not a duplicate

Assuming you mean [this question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/82550/does-really-matters-if-prot-is-an-alien-or-not), it already has 2 votes to reopen, so it seems that at least some of the community agrees with you and it may yet be reopened.

However, if you think it should have been closed as opinion-based, why are you complaining that it was closed as a duplicate? Closed questions can't be answered whatever reason they're closed for, and duplicate-closed questions are actually treated *better* by the system than opinion-based ones.

> for each up vote someone given someone else give a downvote

I checked your profile using moderator tools, and there doesn't appear to be anyone targeting you personally with downvotes. Your posts have simply been poorly received due to their content.

If you'd like to learn more about how to improve your question and answer quality, the [tour](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/tour) and help centre pages such as [What topics can I ask about here?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask), and [How do I write a good answer?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer) might be helpful.

**You'll be welcome to stay here if you feel like giving it another shot.** Let me know if there's anything I can do to help you feel more at home on this site.

Comment: maybe it's opinion based. it lies in the fuzzy area where it could be also accepted as well. Right now someone just told me in comments: "your edit made the answer from duplicate to opinion based" (if it is really opinion based). The content of the answer didn't changed so much, so or it was opinion based, or it was not opinion based already. In any case It was not a duplicate

Comment: @DarioOO - Try not to get too hung up on the close reason. Either way it's off-topic. Is it important to you which reason it got culled?

Comment: I don't believe its off topic. However if it is closed for wrong reason than it means who closed didn't read it. And if not readed then it could as well be a perfectly valid question. Infact there reopen votes. @Valorum anyway I already filled the delete form so the question no longer matters to me. ^^.

Comment: @DarioOO Not necessarily. They might have read it and then come to an incorrect conclusion.

Comment: @DarioOO - Oh, I agree with you. It was closed for the wrong reason. And when it gets reopened, I shall vote for it to be reclosed for the right reason. But in the grand scheme of things,  this is just housekeeping.